# How can I use the onEdit() trigger to timestamp a cell if another cell in the same row is checked "TRUE" in apps script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp, google-apps-script-triggers

I am able to add a timestamp in column 5 using a conditional when I'm comparing the column to a number, but what I am actually trying to do is add a stamp to the corresponding cell in column 5 if a cell in column 1 is checked as TRUE.  When the box is checked, the corresponding cell in column 5 never displays the timestamp:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var attendanceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === true){
    attendanceSheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(new Date());    
  }
  else{
    attendanceSheet.getRange(row,5).setValue("");

  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`if(col === true){`

...with:

`if (e.value === 'TRUE') {`

To get a truly blank value instead of a zero-length text string, replace

`.setValue("")`

...with:

`.setValue(null)`

This makes a difference with functions like `count()` and `isblank()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a follow-up question.  How can I use isBlank() method in combination with e.value to detect if a cell is actually blank/empty or not.  If I need to officially ask this question by posting it, let me know, and I will.

Comment: Please post a new question, and make sure that you describe the _problem_ rather than discussing `e.value`et al. Be clear what you mean by _"cell is actually blank/empty"_, i.e., do you want the behavior that matches that of `isblank(A1)` or the behavior that matches that of `not(not(len(A1)))`.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I will rephrase and post the question.